# How to listen for an api update in Python / Flask

Tags: json, api, flask, python-requests, flask-socketio

I've managed to connect to an api and request data `account_balance` but how can I keep the connection open to listen to that particular api address to be notified when it is updated, i.e. in this case when a transaction occurs?

```
import requests

json = { "action": "account_balance","account": "nano_3t6k35gi95xu6tergt6p69ck76ogmitsa8mnijtpxm9fkcm736xtoncuohr3" }

test = requests.post("https://nanoverse.io/api/node",json=json).json()
print(test)
```

So far I've tried using `flask-socketio` but none of the examples seem to do what I'm specifically asking for.

Comment: can you be more specific, do you mean when url changes or do you mean when content from url changes ?

Comment: @DatoDT when the content changes, so, in this case it'll be when the account_balance changes.

Answer (score 0):

The code above is sending an account balance via HTTP post to some server. I assume that the server at the URL is the Flask server you are talking about. Here is a great tutorial on how to get started with Flask, including how to parse requests: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04. What you want to do is set up a route for `/api/node` and that Python method will be called each time that URL receives a POST. Put your logic for analyzing transactions in there and you're all set.

Comment: It's the other way around: the url is the api I'm trying to connect to from my Flask app. I've connected successfully to the api, but my question is how to keep that connection open so I can be alerted when the 'account_balance' changes? Thanks!